# Parsing File with Control Charactors

Tags: c#, char

I have this file which has control chars in it like decimal 29, 30. In note pad++ these come out to GS, RS respectively. In C# I'm doing a File.ReadAllLines... then for each line I need to split the entire line on these control chars.

Lets' say I have a line as in:

1RSACCTGS2RS718GS3RS425...

The elements I would expect are 1, ACCT, 2, 718, 3, 425...

I mean I can put the line into a toCharArray then check each char if it is a control as in:

if (char.IsControl(c)) but I don't think that's too efficient. A regex would be nice I think but not sure how to write it. Any ideas?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string.Split` method, and pass it an array of control characters on which you would like to split:

```
// Add other special characters on which you'd like to split to the array below
var tokens = line.Split(new[] {(char) 29, (char) 30});
```

Now `tokens` contains an array of substrings of the original line that were separated by the special characters. Multiple special characters in a row are ignored.